# Converting letter 'A' to number 0 vb

Tags: vb.net, string

I have a string "abc defg h"

I wanted to translate each letter into the corresponding number for example 'A' as '00', 'B' as '01'

eg

'hello' --> '06 04 10 10 14'

ps would a dictionary help at all with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How will you handle non-letters? How will you handle spaces?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You examples do not match up.  Should H be 6 or 7?  This is a basic example, but it only handles letters well, spaces and punctuation you will have to determine how you want to handle:

```
    Dim value As String = "HELLO"
    For Each character In value.ToUpper()
        Debug.Print((Asc(character) - 65).ToString("00"))
    Next
```

Comment: If instead of hardcoding Asc('A') as 65 you use `Asc(character) - Asc('A')`, then your only assumption is that the alphabetic characters are consecutive.