# Converting string with letters and numbers to decimal only numbers

Tags: c#, converters

I'm working with `RFID Reader`, and it became with a software demo that has some different types of reading a `rfid tag`, like:

`Hexadecimal`,`Decimal`,`Ascii`, `Abatrack` etc...

The `Abatrack` documentation  says:

`Shows the CardID converted to decimal with 14 digits`.

I have a CardID = `01048CABFB` then with this protocol it shows me `00004371295227`
`where the first four zeroes were added by the software`

It converts a `string` with letters and numbers to `decimal` with only numbers.  how may I do that ?

I've found [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9162557/1919644) , but it's in `VB`.

Comment: Note, that VB answer you've linked would not help you with hex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert from hexadecimal to decimal, you can do this:

```
string hexString = "01048CABFB";
long intVal = Int64.Parse(hexString, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
// intVal = 4371295227
```

Comment: The edited answer is good up to `9223372036854775807` or, in hex `7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFF`. Comfortably exceeding the 14 digits specified in the question, hence my +1.

Comment: @MikeChamberlain The default value of the ID `01048CABFB` isn't `Ascii` ? Because now I have to conver this value to `Hexadecimal` and there is only numbers...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean.  A hex number may not contain any letters at all but still be hexadecimal.  For instance, 99 in hex is 153 in decimal. If the default value "isn't Ascii" then what is it?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Convert.ToInt64() which allows you to specify base 16 (hexadecimal):

```
        string hexFromRFID = "01048CABFB";
        Int64 decFromRFID = Convert.ToInt64(hexFromRFID, 16);
        Console.WriteLine("Hex: " + hexFromRFID + " = Dec: " + decFromRFID);
```

Comment: Worked. But could you explain to me what's the difference between your method and Mike's ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199470/whats-the-main-difference-between-int-parse-and-convert-toint32 - short answer is that Convert.ToInt32 calls Int32.Parse internally, with an extra check to return 0 if the argument is null.